# Radio button in Yii gridview

Tags: yii, cgridview

I have an array of activeRecord objects (from a `model()->findAll()` call) that I pass to a CGridView.
In that grid I need a column that has a radio button for each entry which has a record attribute as it's value.

So in my controller `UserController.php` I have:

```
$users = User::model()->findAll('name=? and surname=?', array($name,$surname));
$this->render('transfer_step_2',array('users'=>$users,));
```

In my view `transfer_step_2.php` I have tried among others:

```
<?php  $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
            'type'=>'striped condensed',
            'id'=>'user-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
                    'data'=>$users)),
            'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
            'columns'=>array(
                'name',
                'surname',
                'telephone',
                'email',
                array(
                    'header'=>'Select',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'value'=>"CHtml::radioButton('user_id['.$data->id.']',false)"
                ),
            ),
        )); ?>
```

When the view is rendered an internal server error occurs with the message that $data is an unknown variable on the line where the Chtml::radioButton is.

How would I achieve what I want, i.e. a list of users from which I can select only one, submit the form and then do processing logic depending on the user id that was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

you have something wrong:

```
array(
                    'header'=>'Select',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'value'=>"CHtml::radioButton('user_id['.$data->id.']',false)"
                ),
```

this is true:

```
array(
                    'header'=>'Select',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'value'=>"CHtml::radioButton('user_id[".$data->id."]',false)"
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your answer didn't work either, you sent me down the right track.
What worked was:

```
array(
        'header'=>'Select',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>'CHtml::radioButton("users[$data->id]",false)',
    ),
```

What I ended up with in the end is:

```
array(
        'header'=>'Select',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>'CHtml::radioButton("user",false,array(
                        "value"=>"$data->id"
                        ))',
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'style'=>'text-align:center'
                ),
    ),
```

Which produces the following html for each row:

```
<td style="text-align:center"><input type="radio" id="user" name="user" value="22"></td>
```

Comment: Really? I cannot see how users[$data->id] was evaluated. What is an example of your HTML markup for the radiobutton?